# PHP: Regular exp to get the last number from exactly string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get the string that match with original and with number in the end.

I got these strings:

```
mod_courts2
mod_courts_config
mod_courts_config2
```

From these strings I want the one that matches only with "mod_courts" with number in the end.

I'm doing this:

```
if (strpos($t, "mod_courts") !== FALSE) {
  preg_match('/^\w+(\d+)$/U', $t, $match);
  echo $match;
}
```

This returns me `"mod_courts2"` and `"mod_courts_config2"`, I just want `"mod_courts2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply, you can do:

`/^(mod_courts\d+)$/`

However, if you want exactly the following format: `sometext_somettext2`, you can use the following regex:

`/^([a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+\d+)$/`
or
`/^([^_]+_[^_]+\d+)$/`

#### Demos

http://regex101.com/r/jP8iC1
http://regex101.com/r/tI1uX8
http://regex101.com/r/fX8pO5

Answer (score 2):

Use the following regex:

```
/^[a-z]+_[a-z]+(\d+)$/
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - assert position at the beginning of the string
- `[a-z]+` - match any alphabet one or more times
- `_` - match a literal undescore character
- `[a-z]+` - match any alphabet one or more times
- `(\d+)` - match (and capture) any digit from 0 to 9 one or more times
- `$` - assert position at the end of the string

**Test cases:**

```
$array = array(
    'mod_courts2',
    'mod_courts_config',
    'mod_courts_config2'
);

foreach ($array as $string) {
    if(preg_match('/^[a-z]+_[a-z]+(\d+)$/i', $string, $matches)) {
        print_r($matches);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => mod_courts2
    [1] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^mod_courts\d+$
```

this should do it

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```
^mod_courts[0-9]+$
```

Meaning `mod_courts` followed by a number (and only that, thanks to `^$` matching the beginning and end of the string). No need for the `strpos` check.